# Show icon in specific object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am rendering a list using `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="pet in pets">
  <h2 ng-bind="pet.name"></h2>
  <i class="icon favorite" ng-class="pet.fav ? 'ion-ios7-heart' : 'ion-ios7-heart-outline'" ng-click="toggleFav(pet._id,$event)"></i>
  <i class="LOADING ICON TO SHOW" ng-show="something?"></i>
</div>
```

[image: app]

The heart button is to toggle the 'like' of the item. I want to hide that heart and show another icon (a loading) when the user taps it. But ONLY on the tapped item.

I was trying with `ng-show` but that obviously is showing/hiding the heart in all the items of my list.

Someone have some idea (perhaps something with `$index`), or had to do something similar in their project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

Create a property called currentIndex in controller and set it in your toggleFav function by sending the $index to that function, when user taps on the heart icon.

then in your ng-show, you can use ng-show="currentIndex == $index" and you can reset the currentIndex to -1 or something when done.

Comment: But, I think this is going to show the loading icon in all the pets that aren´t  liked. I managed to do it using something like you commented yesterday: `ng-show="$currentIndex == $index"`. If you edit the answer with that I will vote you. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason I thought you were looking to do it on ALL items that were liked. Now it makes sense and I updated my answer. Sorry about the confusion.